# Using Tomcat for home server organization

Tags: tomcat, noip

The created web-application is deployed on Tomcat 9.0. The application is presented by the folder «PhotosClassifier» containing the files transmitted to the browser and by the file PhotosClassifier.war. Both objects are in the folder «webapps».
The application operates on the home computer in the imitation mode with the domain name localhost:8080/PhotosClassifier.
The Tomcat file «server.xml» contains the following descriptors:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />

<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
```

Now I want to test the application work from the remote computer that is to use a home server based on Tomcat 9.0. For this goal I have registered on the «no-ip» site, selected the domain name and downloaded the application DUC which periodically updates the IP address of my computer.
THE QUESTION: what changes in Tomcat files must I make to run my application from the remote computer. Must the third level component of the domain name coincide with the name of folder «PhotosClassifier»?
Thanks.

Comment: Not clear at all what you want to do. Locally you request http://localhost:8080/PhotosClassifier, and remotely you would request http://yournoip.hopto.org:8080/PhotosClassifier .

Comment: Thanks for the remark! Now I have understood that my computer is in the subnet of my provider. The no-ip DUC sends IP-address of this subnet but not the address of my computer to the no-ip server. In result my Tomcat is not accessible.